# Search and count for single random number in array of 20 integers

Tags: java, arrays, methods, linear-search

I have a program that produces an array of 20 integers. Then produces one single random number in the same span. What I am attempting to do is search the array of 20 integers and count how many times this single random number occurs and print the result or if the integer is not present to display "not present". I feel like I am so close but I am getting an incorrect count for the random integer. Thank you in advance. Perimeteres for the search method:
•       The method datatype is void because no data will be returned.

•       It will have three parameters – the integer array, the size of the array, and the value it will be searching for in the array.

•       It will search through the array and count how many times the value was found.

•       It will then either print out how many times the value was found or that the value was not found.

My code and sorry if it is not indented properly, still figuring this out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main{
 public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();
   public int[] createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}

public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Single # is: " + (RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1)); 
}

public void searchArray(int[] randomNumbers,int numSearch) {
int count = 0;
for (int i : randomNumbers) {
    if (i == numSearch) {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("Single #" + numSearch + " was not found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Single # "+ numSearch + " was found " + count + "   times");
}
}




public void run() {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 1;
    do {
        int[] numbers = new int[20];
        numbers = createNum(numbers);
        printNum(numbers);
        int numSearch = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
        searchArray(numbers, numSearch);
        System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");
        x = inputReader.nextInt();
    } while (x == 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main go = new Main();
    go.run();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You've already done the work of creating a search method, you're just not calling it. Modify your `searchArray` method to print out the number of occurrences at the end since it's a requirement that you do.

```
public void searchArray(int[] randomNumbers, int numSearch) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i : randomNumbers) {
        if (i == numSearch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("Single #" + numSearch + " was not found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Single # "+ numSearch + " was found " + count + " times");
    }
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
searchArray(numbers, numSearch);
```

Comment: How would I determine what integer to search for since the integer is randomly generated and how would I print out a display when the random number is not found?

Comment: @kidbone222, I updated so that it prints out a "not found" message when count is 0. Yes, you can use your random number as a parameter, I updated my answer to reflect how you would do so.

Comment: @ robotlos I understand to call the array I would place in the void run method, however when this is done I get an error that the symbol for numSearch cannot be found. Do know why this would be?

Comment: @kidbone222, you need to call searchArray(numbers, numSearch);
after line `int numSearch = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;` in your `run() ` method.

Comment: thank you I had literally just figured it out before I checked back and was going to thank you. Now the only issue is I got a single # of 6, but it counted for a different number and not how many times 6 appeared..weird @robotlos

Comment: I tried changing the index to my previously stated index and still received the same type of error, it seems to be just picking a random number within the original array and counting rather than counting how many times the single number appears. @robotlos

Comment: @ robotlos I am going to edit my code on here to show you what is happening once the program is run

Comment: @kidbone222 Are you trying to search for a specific number or a random one?

Comment: I am searching for whatever the single random number is that is generated after the first group of 20 numbers is generated and placed in the array

Comment: @kidbone222 Then what you want to do is `searchArray(numbers, numbers[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You've made a little mistake in your `run()` method`:

```
int numSearch = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
System.out.println("Number found this many times: "+ numSearch);
```

This gives you a random number from one to 10, but you want to count the actual apperence of `numbers[0]`, so you have to use your `searchArray()` method.

Therefore you have to add a return type and return `count`:

```
public int searchArray(int[] randomNumbers,int numSearch) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int i : randomNumbers) {
            if (i == numSearch) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    return count;
 }
```

Then you get your count by:

```
int numSearch = searchArray(numbers, numbers[0]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I must do this with a void rather than int because no data is to be returned. Here are the parameters for this method: 
  The method datatype is void because no data will be returned. 

•       It will have three parameters – the integer array, the size of the array, and the value it will be searching for in the array. 

•       It will search through the array and count how many times the value was found.

•       It will then either print out how many times the value was found or that the value was not found. @Dimi

Comment: Then put the `System.out.println()` in your `searchArray` method, because you can't access the local variable `count` otherwise.

Comment: But you also could return `count` like I did in my answer, then you can check `if (count == 1)` so it means the array doesn't contains the number you're searching for, because the first element is always the number you are searching for.

Comment: @Dimi...I'm not sure what you mean, so make it look like this: public int searchArray(int[] randomNumbers,int numSearch) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i : randomNumbers) {
        if (i == numSearch) {
                count++;                                                                                 int numSearch = searchArray(numbers, numbers[0]);
            System.out.println("Single # was found: "+ numSearch+" times");

Comment: Did you return `count` at the end of the `searchArray` method ? 
Then it schould work properly.

Answer (score 0):

@Dimi So something like this:

public int searchArray(int[] randomNumbers,int numSearch) {
        int count = 0;

```
    for(int i : randomNumbers) {
        if (i == numSearch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
  int numSearch = searchArray(numbers, numbers[0]);
        System.out.println("Single # was found: "+ numSearch+" times");
```